# Internal Storage issues

Tags: internal-storage, insufficient-memory

I have a Motorola Moto E2 phone. The [product info page](http://www.motorola.com/we/products/moto-e-gen-2) shows it comes with 8GB of internal storage, but I am only seeing 5GB of space when I look at it through my USB connection.

[image: 4.98GB]

Every app that can move has been moved to my 16GB SD card.

The only thing that I cannot move are the Android updates and the data from my Text conversations.

I cannot stop the Android updates, and I need the Text history for legal issues.

How do I stop this phone from running out of space? I have had it for only 6-months.

Comment: I have also gone into every app on the phone to clear the cache.

Comment: Answered already many times: Guess where the OS resides. You've to subtract that. As the `/system` partition with recent devices easily goes up to 2 or 3 GB (even more with some Samsung devices), there is no space missing at all. It's just confusing advertisement. See: [Why the Galaxy has 25GB instead of 32GB](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/24304/16575)

Comment: @Izzy, I was not asking why my phone reports 5GB for an 8GB drive. You missed the point of my question completely. My point is that NOTHING is installed on my phone's drive. You can see that all of my content is installed on my SD card. Still, my 6-month old phone is out of space because of Android Updates. Again, **How do I stop this phone from running out of space?**

Comment: Apologies – I indeed misunderstood your question. I've just added the `insufficient-memory` tag (which should fit your issue) to your post. As these kind of questions pop up here very frequently, we've collected some information and first-aid [in its tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info). Could you please check with that? Afterwards, please [edit] your post again to reflect what you've tried and where you're stuck – or let us know if (and how) you were able to solve your problem. Depending on which, I'd then re-open the question. Fingers crossed!